# Cannot use an entityset inside my linq to sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq, sequence, local

when i try to query database to retrive activity for selected crew, i give "Loca Sequence Error"

this is the code:

```
private Lst_active as new entityset(of Activity)   
private crw_list as new entityset(of Crew)

checklistbox.Items.addrange(Dbase.Crew)
```

then i choose from all crew in checklistbox and selected crews insert into entityset of Crew for further use.

```
crw_list.addrange(Checkedlistbox.checkeditems)

Lst_active.AddRange(From x In DBase.Stored_Activities Join z In crw_list On x.EMP_NO  Equals z.EMP_NO
                    Select x)
```

is there any way around? or im doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find the solution, just changed place of two parts of query.

```
     From z In crw_list Join x In DBase.Stored_Activities  On x.EMP_NO  Equals z.EMP_NO
                Select x
```

it changes query from linq to sql to linq to object with a sql join query included.

Comment: This one takes the entire table into memory, and perform join as in-memory query, which is much less efficient then DB.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how your model looks like, but following concept should work:

```
Dim active = (From x In DBase.Stored_Activities
              Join z In DBase.Stored_Crews On x.EMP_NO  Equals z.EMP_NO
              Select x).ToList()
```

**Update**

If you have a local in-memory collection and you need items with a field matching one within that collection, use `Contains` instead:

```
From x in DBase.StoredActivities
Where localList.Contains(x.EMP_NO)
select x
```

Your list should contain the *joining column** only, in this case should be made from `crw_list.Select(Function(x) x.EMP_NO)`.

Comment: yes, but i need to use a local sequence. i'm gonna edit the question.

Comment: i dont know if there is any other way to use a local list instead of entityset to use in query.

Comment: Check my update. You should probably go with `Contains`.